# using resolver with router

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular5

I have 2 differents paths for the same component, and they use resolve data:

```
//app.routing:
const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    canActivate: [LoggedInGuard],
    children: [
        {path: '', redirectTo: '/path1', pathMatch: 'full'},
        {path: 'path1', loadChildren: 'app/myModule.module#MyModuleModule'},
        {path: 'path2', loadChildren: 'app/myModule.module#MyModuleModule'}  
    ]
},
{path: '**', redirectTo: ''}
];


export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

In myModule.routing:

```
const MY_MODULE_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {path: '', component: MyModule2Component, resolve: {data: MyModule2Resolver}}
];


export const myModuleRouting = RouterModule.forChild(MY_MODULE_ROUTES);
```

All this works fine.

Now I would like to control routing from MyModule2Resolver:

```
@Injectable()
export class  MyModule2Resolver implements Resolve<any[]> {
 constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

 resolve(): Promise<any> {
      //Different action depending on path1 or path2 but
     // I have not this info in activatedRoute or router
 }
}
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `activatedRoute` contains a property `url`, which contains information about the `url`. Use it and write your logic

Comment: activatedRoute is empty in resolver, but I found it, if resolve(data) in data._routerState.url is the value. Thanks